# Awk: Extract lines when columns sum within a range

Tags: awk

Using Awk to extract lines from a file where $3 - $2 is between 200 and 400.

Command I am using:

```
awk '{ if ($3 - $2 > 199 && < 401) print $0}' Input_File
```

Error message:

```
  awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    { if ($3 - $2 > 199 && >>>  < <<<  401) print $0}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

The command works if I use just one parameter e.g.  `awk '{ if ($3 - $2 > 199) print $0}' Input_File`, but not when I use `&&`. How do I fix this?

Example Input_File:

```
A    1000    1500
B    1000    1300
C    1000    1100
D    1000    1200
```

Example desired output:

```
B    1000    1300
D    1000    1200
```

Comment: In which programming language would `x - y > 199 && < 401` be valid syntax? Awk syntax is very similar to that of any other Algol-base language (C, Pascal, Ada, etc., etc.) so just think about how to write whatever you want to express in that `if` statement in whatever language you're familiar with and then use that same syntax in awk and it'll almost certainly be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition after `&&` is incomplete. You may just use:

```sh
awk '$3-$2 > 199 && $3-$2 < 401' file

B    1000    1300
D    1000    1200
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a variable with the difference of 3rd and 2nd columns and then could use it in conditions.

```
awk '{ val=($3 - $2);if ( val > 199 && val < 401) print $0}' Input_File
```

***Why OP's attempt is getting error:*** OP is using `if ($3 - $2 > 199 && < 401)` which is wrong because of difference of 3rd and 2nd column is NOT mentioned 2 time(after `&&`, before `< 401`) for each condition(either separated by OR/AND condition) condition should be mentioned separately. so it should be like: `if (($3 - $2 > 199) && ($3 - $2 < 401))`. IMHO making variable will be better to avoid getting differences 2 times, get difference one time into a variable and use it in different conditions..

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to repeat the calculation you can do this instead

```
$ awk '(d=$3-$2)>199 && d<401' file
```